# Linux Root volume partition without losing the data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, virtual-machine

We have this scenario : we want to increase the disk space of one of our vm

```
root@Test-01:~# blkid
/dev/vda2: UUID="0eae0eb4-92ed-45ec-aa99-6d606f17e70a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="06cf22a2-02"
/dev/vda1: UUID="b5e223df-9f41-4e4c-aa8d-e4529fa28424" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="06cf22a2-01"


root@Test-01:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    254:0    0  150G  0 disk
├─vda1 254:1    0   46G  0 part /
└─vda2 254:2    0  104G  0 part [SWAP]
```

As its a Not LVM I have tried the below , but its wont work

```
parted /dev/vda resizepart 1 100%

resize2fs /dev/vda1

root@Test-01:~# parted /dev/vda print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        1024B   1049kB  1048kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  49.4GB  49.4GB  primary  ext4
 2      49.4GB  161GB   112GB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

we need the swap to go in the last in memory block, swap is in between

we have 112GB   primary Linux-swap(v1)

now we want to increase first partition end block to 156 instead of 49.4 gb

now we want to decrease 2nd partition start block to 156 instead of 49.4 gb

we want to increase the root volum with safe option without loosing any data ,

Is Performing the resize operation with parted alone is risky and could lead to data loss? So below doesn't look like safe for me.

```
sudo parted /dev/vda resizepart 1 100%
sudo parted /dev/vda move 2 100%
```

This is a virtual machine not a physical machine we are not a not able to use usb or cd drive there , its a Linux Debian machine .

what is the best way to perform this without losing the root volume data , any help would be apricated .

Comment: You should, and in most cases even cant, modify a drive/partition that is currently mounted and active.
It is possible to resize you partitions, but not while the machine is running the OS off of those drives.

Comment: That being said, as long as the alignments are the same it is possible.
Deactivate swap, set the partition size to something reasonable (i would do this with gdisk and set the swap start to something like -16G - that is 16 GB in front of the last sector - and swap end to the last sector.) Then you modify the systems partition size to be the same start sector, but -16GB end sector)
After that you can resize your filesystem, but this is the step that is impossible to do while the system is running.